# Unable to import downloaded Zelle graphics module in IDLE

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I'm having a trouble downloading the `graphics.py` file and locating at the appropriate directory.

To import the graphics library I downloaded the file at [https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/), then I located at the LIB directory (I also tried at the site-packages directory which is inside the LIB directory).

But when I try to import the library it doesn't works.
The python IDLE just displays

```
import graphics
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import graphics
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphics'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow! You're english isn't that bad don't worry about it.

What I would recommend you do is actually install PIP which can be found here:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Then, once it is installed (and is the correct version), install it from here: https://pypi.org/project/graphics.py/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I just installed the files from https://pypi.org/project/graphics.py/. I wonder where should I have to locate the files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the graphics.py file in the working directory instead of site-packages and try importing it. It should work.

Comment: This would work, but for modules downloaded externally is generally bad practise and should not be encouraged.

Comment: Yes, brother, you are right. Try to install the package using pip command. "pip install graphics.py"

Comment: I'm really appreciated for your comment!